# Como puedo cargar los datos de una pila y cola en una cola nueva

Tags: c++, dev-c++, pilas

Qtal, tengo un inconveniente con un código mío, el problema me pide cargar una pila con datos variados, luego que cargues todos esos datos, se carga una cola con datos variados también, luego de eso cargar intercaladamente los datos de la pila y cola en una nueva cola.
Les comparto el código que tengo:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct pila{
int dato;
struct pila *nextptr;};
typedef struct pila PILA;
typedef PILA *PILAPTR;
void insertar(PILAPTR *, int);
int sacar(PILAPTR *);
int esvacio(PILAPTR );
void imprimir(PILAPTR);
struct cola{
int dato;
struct cola *nextptr;
};
typedef struct cola COLA;
typedef COLA *COLAPTR;

void imprimir(COLAPTR);
int esvacio(COLAPTR);
int desencolar(COLAPTR *,  COLAPTR *);
void encolar(COLAPTR *, COLAPTR *,int);


void insertar(PILAPTR *topPtr, int valor){
PILAPTR nuevoPtr;
nuevoPtr = new(PILA);
if(nuevoPtr!=NULL){
    nuevoPtr->dato = valor;
    nuevoPtr->nextptr = *topPtr;
    *topPtr = nuevoPtr;
    }else{
        cout<<"NO HAY MEMORIA PARA CREAR EL NODO"<<endl;
    }
}
int sacar(PILAPTR *topPtr){
PILAPTR tempPtr;
int valor;

tempPtr = *topPtr;
valor = (*topPtr)->dato;
*topPtr = (*topPtr)->nextptr;
delete(tempPtr);
return valor;
}

void imprimir (PILAPTR q){
if( q == NULL){
    cout<<"PILA VACIA"<<endl;
}else{
    cout<<"LA PILA ES:"<<endl;
    while(q!=NULL){
        cout<<q->dato<<"->";
        q = q->nextptr;
    }
    cout<<"NULL"<<endl;
  }
}
int esvacio(PILAPTR topPtr){
return topPtr == NULL;
}

void encolar(COLAPTR *headPtr, COLAPTR *tailPtr, int valor){
COLAPTR nuevoPtr;

nuevoPtr = new(COLA);

if(nuevoPtr!=NULL){
    nuevoPtr->dato = valor;
    nuevoPtr->nextptr = NULL;

if(esvacio(*headPtr))
*headPtr = nuevoPtr;
else
(*tailPtr)->nextptr = nuevoPtr;

*tailPtr = nuevoPtr;
}else
cout<<"NO HAY MEMORIA"<<endl;

}
int desencolar(COLAPTR *headPtr, COLAPTR *tailPtr){
int valor;
COLAPTR temPtr;
valor = (*headPtr)->dato;
temPtr = *headPtr;
*headPtr = (*headPtr)->nextptr;

if(*headPtr==NULL){
    *tailPtr = NULL;
}
delete(temPtr);
return valor;
}

int esvacio(COLAPTR headPtr){
return headPtr==NULL;
}


void imprimircola(COLAPTR q){
if(q==NULL)
cout<<"COLA VACIA"<<endl;
else{
    cout<<"LA COLA ES:"<<endl;
    while (q!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<q->dato<<"->";
        q=q->nextptr;
    }
cout<<"NULL"<<endl;
}
 }

int main(){
int m,n,x=1;
PILAPTR Pila=NULL,auxpila=NULL;
COLAPTR head=NULL, rear=NULL, auxcola=NULL, newcola=NULL, newrear=NULL;
cout<<"Ingrese numero para la Pila"<<endl;
cin>>m;

while(m!=-99){
    encolar(&newcola,&newrear,m);
    insertar(&Pila,m);
    cout<<"Siga cargando numeros para la Pila hasta que cargue el -99"<<endl;
    cin>>m;
}
cout<<"Ingrese numero para la Cola"<<endl;
cin>>n;
while(n!=-99){
    encolar(&head,&rear,n);
    encolar(&newcola,&newrear,n);
    cout<<"Siga cargando numeros para la Cola hasta que cargue el -99"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
}
 imprimir(Pila);
imprimircola(head);
cout<<"LA NUEVA COLA ES:"<<endl;
imprimircola(newcola);
system("pause");
return 1;
}
```

Lo que no logro hacer todavía es guardar los datos intercalados, y mostrarlos en en pantalla con la impresión. No se en donde debo colocar la funcion o si mi mi condición esta mal. Les agradecería si me ayudarán.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

las funciones que debes implementar para dichas acciones serian:

```cpp
//copia los datos de una pila a otra
pila cp(pila a){
    pila n;
    while(!a.isempty()) n.push(a.pop());
    return n;
}

//copia los datos de una pila y cola intercaladamente
pila cp_inter(pila a,cola b){
    pila n;
    while(!a.isempty() || !b.isempty()){
        if(!a.isempty()){
            n.push(a.pop());
        }
        if(!b.isempty()){
            n.push(b.pop());
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: bueno es un poco diferente al estilo de mi codigo, le adapte a como lo tengo yo y si funciona, te agradezco.